# Unable to get associated TextView value from within onClicked method of Android Switch component

Tags: android, android-layout, listview

I am trying to get the value from a view `(TextView)` when a Switch component within the same parent view (list-view) is toggled. The method which is called when Switch is toggled is:

```
public void onSwitchClicked(View list) {

        Switch mySwitch = (Switch) list.findViewById(R.id.tgl_status);

        // Is the toggle on?
        boolean on = ((Switch) mySwitch).isChecked();

        if (on) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TURN ON: Request sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "TURN OFF: Request sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
}
```

This much code is working as expected, but when I try to retrieve a TextView value of a component which is present in the same list-view, the program crashes. Here is how I am trying to do it (I am putting this code within `onSwitchClicked()` method's body):

```
 TextView tV = (TextView) list.findViewById(R.id.pid);
 String pid = tV.getText().toString();
```

Consider the XML of list-view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="65dip"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    >

    <!-- Product id (pid) - will be HIDDEN - used to pass to other activity -->
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pid" <!-- **this is the value I want** ... -->
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:visibility="gone" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/statusT"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:textSize="17dip"
        android:layout_below="@+id/name"
        />

    <Switch <!-- **when this Switch is toggled** -->
        android:id="@+id/tgl_status"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_width="125dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="6dip"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:textOff="OFF"
        android:textOn="ON"
        android:onClick="onSwitchClicked"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I want the value of `pid` TextView to be assigned to `pid` String. How can I achieve that?

Here's the LOGCAT:

```
W/dalvikvm(7749): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41560ba8)
E/AndroidRuntime(7749): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(7749): Process: com.iotautomationtech.androidapp, PID: 7749
E/AndroidRuntime(7749): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not execute method of the activity
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3823)
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     at android.widget.CompoundButton.performClick(CompoundButton.java:100)
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18422)
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001)
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(7749): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3818)
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     ... 12 more
E/AndroidRuntime(7749): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     at com.iotautomationtech.androidapp.AllDevicesActivity.onSwitchClicked(AllDevicesActivity.java:100)
E/AndroidRuntime(7749):     ... 15 more
```

Some help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `onSwitchClicked(View switchView)` receive the switch view as argument.

The switchView and the TextView you are looking for are in the same relativeLayout. So here is how to get the textView :

```
public void onSwitchClicked(View switchView) {
        RelativeLayout relativeLayout = (RelativeLayout)switchView.getParent();
        TextView tV = (TextView)relativeLayout.findViewById(R.id.pid);
        String pid = tV.getText().toString();
        ...
}
```